# filter/search using splice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter the results of an api response list using splice. This is the code of the api which feeds the list:

```
function listData (){
   $http.get('/api/dataBrands')
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.list = data.data.Response;
});
    }
```

And the HTML view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in list">
            <th>{{info.Id}}</th>
            <th>{{info.Name}}</th>
```

The elements of that list, are the names of brands. Then, I have another api where i have all the brands with accidents. What i'm doing is search the brands on the list of accidents. If there's a brand with accident, with splice i have to filter. This is my code so far:

```
$scope.pursuit = function(){

        $scope.bringItOn = allInfo.get({Id: $scope.Id})
                        .$promise
                        .then(function(data){


                           for(var d = 0; d< data.Response.length; d++){
                                for(var e = 0; e< $scope.list.length; e++){
                                   if(data.Response[d].Id == $scope.list[e].Id){
                                       $scope.cut = $scope.list.splice($scope.list, 1);
                                        console.log($scope.list);
                             }

                                       }
                                        }

                        });

    }
```

`allInfo.get` is declared on my factory. This is the HTML view for the search:

```
    <div class="x input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here!" ng-model="Id">
<span class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" ng-click="pursuit()">Search</button>
</span>
</div>
```

The code seems to work but not as i want. Per example, let's supose i have three values:

```
1 Mars
2 Volvo
3 Pepsi
```

If I search "Mars", it splice the first value -which is Mars-. If i search "Pepsi", it splice Mars and Volvo, and shows only Pepsi. As i see, is "deleting" the first value.

What can i do to make my code works fine and splice all the brands except the value that i'm searching?

Hope you can help me.

I'm  using angularjs, javascript and bootstrap.

Comment: `splice()` is destructive. Use `Array#filter()` instead

Comment: @charlietfl and how i show the result on my html view? can i use ng-show/ng-hide?

Comment: Wouldn't have to if you filter the array